# How to add this to $ with other ids ? query

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I implement this code :

```
$("ID5").click(function{
   $("#Id1,#Id2" + this).hide();
});
```

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/), It add elements to the set of matched elements.

```
$("#ID5").click(function{
   $("#Id1,#Id2").add(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.addBack()` too:

```
$("#ID5").click(function{
   $("#Id1,#Id2").addBack().hide();
});
```

***The .addBack() method causes the previous set of DOM elements in the traversal stack to be added to the current set.***